# M2 - Uninstall language pack

Tags: composer, magento2.3, language-package

I installed a language pack using composer.

```
$ composer require mageplaza/magento-2-german-language-pack:dev-master
$ php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now when I try to uninstall again, using this command:
`php bin/magento i18n:uninstall mageplaza_de_de`

I get the following message:

```
Package mageplaza_de_de is not a Magento language and will be skipped.
Nothing is removed.
```

This is what's in the `registration.php`

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'mageplaza_de_de',
    __DIR__
);
```

How can I uninstall this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself.
`php bin/magento i18n:uninstall` was already the right command for removing a language pack.
But the name of the language pack is what's written in the composer.json and was added to the project with `composer require`. Using the `<vendor>_<module>` syntax like for uninstalling modules doesn't work here.

So the full command that worked for me was:
`php bin/magento i18n:uninstall mageplaza/magento-2-german-language-pack`
(Without the :dev-master)

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall a module through composer if it was installed using composer. If yes then issue command:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r mageplaza_de_de
```

-r flag removes module data. 
then issue:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If module was not installed through composer:

- remove the module directory `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>`
- drop module database tables (if it created any)
- remove entry from core_config_data and setup_module tables

Run command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: This is what I already tried before, but I get the following error: `Unknown module(s): mageplaza_de_de`